# Django-oscar less css

Tags: css, django, django-oscar

```
    OSCAR_USE_LESS = True
DEBUG = True
```

In Oscar Documentation, it says that you can view compiled css via browser after a reload(F5) but 
my pages show up, without a CSS effect on them. What am I missing ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="{% static "oscar/less/styles.less" %}" />
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I removed in the line ***{% if use_less and debug %}*** these words ***and debug*** in the file **templates/oscar/layout.html** and it is worked for me. In the file **settings.py** I have ***DEBUG = True*** so I don't know why it didn't work.

**Old**

```
{% block cdn_scripts %}
  {{ block.super }}
  {% if use_less and debug %}
    {# Load the on-the-fly less compiler. Never do this in production. #}
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"></script>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**New**

```
{% block cdn_scripts %}
  {{ block.super }}
  {% if use_less %}
    {# Load the on-the-fly less compiler. Never do this in production. #}
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js"></script>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```